# Функция, меняющая строковое поле по его имени

Tags: typescript

Есть функция, которая принимает объект и имя свойства этого объекта, свойство должно быть типа string.

Почти все работает за исключение того что не могу присвоить val[key] = "value";

Можно как то решить эту проблему?

```
let obj = {
    name: "some",
    id: 5,
};

type SubType<Base, Condition> = Pick<Base, {
    [Key in keyof Base]: Base[Key] extends Condition ? Key : never
}[keyof Base]>;

function foo<T, K extends keyof SubType<T,string>>(val: T, key: K) {
    val[key] = "value"; // TS2322: Type '"value"' is not assignable to type 'T[K]'.
}

foo(obj, "name");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы сделал [по-другому](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=10&pc=18#code/DYUwLgBA9gRgVhAvBA3gWAFAWxAdgQwFsQAuCAIgGcpjyAaTHCASwBMyBWBjAXwG5MmAGYBXXAGMwzKLghCoUADwBpCCAAeYELlaUIlMACdmuAOYA+ABQA3fMDIoIAbQDWIAJ4tZygLpkDxmYQPHQQbu5kygCUqIw4tsCuHj5IFAkiIOQCvIIY8lCWsHCh5AS0UXxAA):

```
let obj = {
    name: "some",
    id: 5,
};

function foo<K extends string>(val: { [key in K]: string }, key: K) {
    val[key] = "value";
}

foo(obj, "name");
```